# Which is correct , on first dates or on first date?

Tags: phrase-meaning, parallelism

In the sentence in block quote below, is it correct to say "on first dates" ?
Or is the correct form "on first date?"
Is it supposed to be "on first few dates?"

> During job interviews , ON FIRST DATES , and when meeting new coworkers , people make assessments of one another very quickly.

Comment: How many dates are you talking about? Generally, people only talk about an initial, single date: *on the first date*. But if you want to talk about multiple dates, you would normally qualify it in some say: *on the first few dates*, *on the first five dates*. It's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: Here is the complete paragraph.    During job interviews , ON FIRST DATES , and when meeting new coworkers , people make assessments  of one another very quickly.

Comment: It's appropriate _in this context_ because the sentence refers to the 'first date' as a type of occasion, not to a particular couple's first few dates.

Comment: To be fair, I think it is a good question. Upvote from me.

Comment: With the *full context*, the use of the plural in *on first dates* now makes sense. When asking future questions, be sure to provide this kind of context from the start.

Comment: @JasonBassford The thing to remember is that, although every established couple (except for some people in arranged marriages) had one _first date_ with _each other_ but the majority of people will have had a number of _first dates_ with _other people_. Some of these first dates will have resulted in longer attachments but some of them will have been the only date the incompatible couples had. This is the parallel between _first dates_, _job interviews_ and _meeting coworkers_.

Answer (score 1):

> During job interviews, on first dates, and when meeting new
>   coworkers, people make assessments of one another very quickly.

It may seem odd that "first" (which usually refers to only one thing) is used with the plural "dates". While a person may only have one "first date" with any single person, they may have many "first dates" each with a different person (one first date with person A, one first date with person B, etc.). The statement in the example sentence applies to any first date with any person, so it applies to "first dates" in general.

The phrasing of "first dates" also fits with the parallel rule. *job interviews* is plural. *first dates* is plural. *new coworkers* is plural. Everything is plural; everything is parallel.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that "first dates" is plural for the sake of the parallelism, but it should be plural in this context even in the absence of any parallelism. Perhaps you can point out that "first dates" is plural because while you have only one first date with any given person, you can have many first dates (each with a different person) over the course of a lifetime.

Comment: @Tashus Is that distinction relevant?

Comment: If you mean the distinction between "plural for the sake of parallelism" and "plural because of context", I think it is relevant for helping learners understand the language. If you mean the distinction between "one first date with a specific person" and "many first dates with many people", I think it is relevant in explaining what the aforementioned context is.

Comment: In other words, I think it is better for the learner to understand "oh, it is plural here because it is referring to any first dates in general" rather than letting them think "oh, it's just plural because it fits with the other words." If you don't agree, I would be happy to provide an alternative answer.

Comment: I am talking about "people" in general. And people go to job interviews, go on first dates, and meet new co-workers. Everything is taken generally, *and* it fits with the other words. I mean both at the same time.

Comment: The answer seems to indicate only that the parallelism requires the plural. It seems to me that the asker is confused why "first" is used with a plural, so I think it is important to explain why the phrasing is correct in the context. If you like, I can make an edit, or I can provide an alternative answer.

Comment: I have to leave in a moment for work. Feel free to make an edit, though.

Comment: Done. I hope you find it fitting with the rest of your answer.